# How to print only index of an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Using select query am select some data from database.

i fetched data using while loop.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
 {

}
```

now i want to print only index of $row.

i tried to print using following statements but it prints index and value(Key==>Value)

```
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    echo $key ;
}
```

and i tried array_keys() also bt it is also not helpful to me.

```
echo implode(array_keys($row));
```

please help to get out this.

i need to print only index.

Comment: What do u mean by index? Index of an array (in your case columns names)  or maybe id of record?

Comment: i need to print key not value.

Comment: Are you using same `$row` in first and second loops? If yes - then you're overwriting it in first loop and then you'll get only 1 row in second

Comment: am using only one loop.

Answer (score 2):

You are fetching the results row as both associative array and a numeric array (the default), see the manual on [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php).

If you need just the numeric array, use:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query1, MYSQL_NUM))
```

By the way, you should switch to PDO or mysqli as the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Comment: Simple and best without additional Work :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should pass separator(glue text) in Implode function.

For comma separated array keys, you can use below code.

```
echo implode(",",array_keys($row));
```

Comment: using above statement also it printing 0,sa,1,ff,2df   like this but i need only key vales 0,1,2.

Comment: then what do you want to do?

Comment: The `glue` parameter is optional -- `implode()` can work without it.

Comment: @sandeep jeroen gave best best solution for your question.

Answer (score 0):

The `$row` variable in your `while` loop gets overwritten on each iteration, so the `foreach` won't work as you expect it to.

Store each `$row` in an array, like so:

```
$arr = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
    $arr[] = $row;
}
```

Now, to print the array keys, you can use a simple `implode()`:

```
echo implode(', ', array_keys($arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

$query1 from while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query1)) should be the result from

```
$query1 = mysql_result("SELECT * FROM table");
//then
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
```

To get only the keys use [mysql_fetch_row](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)

```
$query = "SELECT fields FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
  print_r(array_keys($row));
}
```